# outputing data in different order

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

My JS script allows me to output sequential user input in the order below (counter iteration and \t spacing):

```
1. ab     2. bc    3. cd
4. de     5. ef    6. fg
7. gh     8. hi    9. ij
10. jk    11. ys
```

The user is given only 1 input field to enter 1 entry at a time. 11 is not the last entry as they can continue their work inputting more. 
**How can I display** ?

```
1. ab     5. ef    9. ij
2. bc     6. fg    10. jk
3. cd     7. gh    11. ys
4. de     8. hi
```

My script:

```
dnm_data.list_count += 1;
var data_output =  "<b>" + dnm_data.list_count + ".</b> " + data;

if (dnm_data.list_count % 3 === 0)
    data_output  = "<div class='col-xs-4'>" + data_output + "</div><div class='clearfix'></div>";
else 
    data_output = "<div class='col-xs-4'>" + data_output + "</div>";

$("#log-wrapper")  .append( data_output )
                   .addClass("bg-success")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Could you output them vertically in a div rather than across, and then close it and open a new one next to it at the appropriate time?

Answer (score 2):

You could put every input value in an array, and after each input split it to 3 equal chunks of data (or something) and rebuild the whole thing.

However, you may want to look into css3 columns. You simply append to a wrapper like you do now, and css will take care of the rest.

https://jsfiddle.net/5q3tqcrm/

Tried it with `div`, and `ul / li`. The only flaw is that it goes to 2 columns when there's 4 values, because after shifting it always clears 2 places in the 3rd column.

Info & resources: http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20column